# sort, uniq and put number of occurrence on the right

Tags: bash

I have multiple files that has a string in each line. For example:

```
abc
cde
abc
efg
```

I would like to count occurrence of each string. I know how to do so with the following code:

```
cat * | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

but It prints:

```
    2 abc
    1 cde
    1 efg
```

How do I delete the starter space and move the number to the right of the string like this:

```
abc,2
cde,1
efg,1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pipe the output to the following awk:

```
... | awk '{print $2 "," $1}'
```

$1 and $2 represent the first and second column, respectively. Space concatenates the arguments.

Comment: Actually, the spaces can be omitted: `... | awk '{print $2","$1}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use awk command:
`awk -F"," '{file[$1]++} END{for(i in file){print i","file[i]}}' <filename> | sort`

FYI this is generalized command

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single `awk` for this.

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END{for(i in a){print i","a[i] |  "sort"}}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk and controlling array scanning order to sort the data:

```
$ awk '
{ a[$0]++ }                               # hash to a counting instances
END {                                     # after processing records
    OFS=","                               # ser output field separator
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"  # set desired array scanning order
    for(i in a)                           # ... for for
        print i,a[i]                      # output
}' file
abc,2
cde,1
efg,1
```